# using python .subprocess for terminal command

Tags: python, terminal, command, subprocess

Hi everyone I want to remove all files/folder on a specific folder and to do that I wrote the following code : ( I want to remove all of the file/folders on the directory saved in co_directory except packages_with_....txt files however I got an error

```
def remove_file():

    remove="sudo rm -rf !(packages_with_diff_branches.txt|packages_with_same_branches.txt)"
    p = subprocess.Popen("""
    %s
    %s""" % (co_directory,remove),shell=True , executable='/bin/bash')
    p.wait()





/bin/bash: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 3: `    sudo rm -rf !(packages_with_diff_branches.txt|packages_with_same_branches.txt)'
```

Is there anyone to help me ? thanks a lot

**EDIT**
**co_directory is global variable**

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this, without using `subprocess`,

The `os` module,

```
import os

filesInDir= [ i for i in os.listdir("/path/to/dir") if i != "yourFile.txt" if i! = "yourFile.txt2" ]
for i in filesInDir:
    os.remove(i)
```

Comment: thanks for comment but How could I prevent to remove the files that I dont want to remove /

Comment: @Eday Also, I don't think `-rf` takes  `!(a|b|` command, you might want to do just this,`sudo rm !(packages_with_diff_branches.txt|packages_with_same_branches.txt)`

Comment: thanks for comment.You were right.It wasnt run until I removed -rf option.Thanks again